# Using Contacts UI has some errors and could not figure out the solutions

Tags: swift

I am doing a very simple app. Single view with one button "add contact" and a table view. When I press the "add contact", I could select the contact and then his/her mobile phone number. This phone number will be added to the table view.
My code is listed as following. When I press "add contact" button, it opens the contact and then I choose one contact and then his mobile phone number. But then there is no response. I did see an error message shown up in the output window:

> [CNUI ERROR] Selection predicates are set but the delegate does not implement contactPicker:didSelectContact: and contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty:. Those predicates will be ignored.

Based on the message, I then tried to add `contactPicker.delegate =self`, then it said there was an error

> can not assign value of "view controller" to "CNContactPickerDelegate"

Then I don't know what to do. Please help.
I also searched the questions before and some are related but I still could not figure out the answers. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
import Contacts

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


    var items = [String]()

    @IBAction func addContact(sender: AnyObject) {

        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()


        contactPicker.delegate = self

        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]



        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate (value:true)

        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(value: true)

        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }


    func contactPicker(picker:CNContactViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty:CNContactProperty) {

        let newitem = contactProperty.value as! CNPhoneNumber

        items.append(String(newitem))

         tableView.reloadData()

          print(newitem.stringValue)


    }




    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return  items.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]



        return UITableViewCell()


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue. I needed to add `CNContactPickerDelegate` in the beginning. And I also fixed one issue in the table view by using only `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Notice that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath` are different methods.

And the following code works:

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
import Contacts

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, CNContactPickerDelegate {


    var items = [String]()

    @IBAction func addContact(sender: AnyObject) {

        let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()


        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
        contactPicker.delegate = self


        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate (value:false)

        contactPicker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(value: true)

        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


    func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

        let newitem = contactProperty.value as! CNPhoneNumber

        items.append(newitem.stringValue)

        tableView.reloadData()

        print(newitem.stringValue)
    }








    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!




    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

         print(items.count)

        return  items.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

        cell!.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]


        return cell!


    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }


}
```

Comment: Great. Accept your own answer if it solves the issue.